# What's the problem with deleting a row from database?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, quoted-identifier

I want to delete a row from my database, but it doesn't work. I've got 2 exception: 
- NumberFormatException: null (it's for the parseInt part in the Servlet)
- PSQLException: ERROR: relation "patients" does not exist... but it does exist!
Can u help me to solve my problem?

DB.java (just the method)

```
public int deletePatient(int patID) {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                String delete = "DELETE FROM \"Patients\" WHERE Patients.PatientID = ?";
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(delete);
                pstmt.setInt(1, patID);
                affectedRows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Connection is not created! 5");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return affectedRows;
    }
    return affectedRows;
}
```

ServletP.java (just the method)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, NumberFormatException {

        try {
            int patID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("patID2"));
            db.deletePatient(patID);
        } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
            n.printStackTrace();
        }

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String htmlRespone = "<html>";
        htmlRespone += "<h2>Action is done!</h2>";
        htmlRespone += "<a href=\"/WebApp/patients\">Back</a>";
        htmlRespone += "</html>";
        writer.println(htmlRespone);
}
```

jsp:

```
<div>
            <form method="POST" action="patients">
                <table border="2" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="patID2"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you created your table(s) using double quotes (which is a really bad idea to begin with). Once you do that, you have to **always** [enclose your table and column names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in double quotes - everywhere.

So

```
"DELETE FROM \"Patients\" WHERE Patients.PatientID = ?"
```

should be:

```
"DELETE FROM \"Patients\" WHERE \"Patients\".\"PatientID\" = ?"
```

Comment: now it's working, thanks, but still got the :NumberFormatException: null

Comment: @vv_wow: that is something entirely different - but you should [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that - only ask one question per question please (provide the input values to the parseInt() function there.